# Swift - Sink doesn't receive newly published values

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to create a simple Combine pattern in Swift that involves downloading data from URL (Async call) and informs the other class once the download has been completed.

The following is a simplified version of what I have (Names are changed for simplification). Another class will simply call `await MainClass.shared.downloadDataFromApi()`:

**MainClass.swift**

```
// .... [Singleton Pattern]
let vm = PublisherClass.shared

private init(){
        print("Initiated")
    
        vm.$downloaded.sink(receiveCompletion: {
            print("received completion \($0)")
        }, receiveValue: {print("received value \($0)")})
    }
    
    func downloadDataFromApi() async {
        await vm.getFromAPI()
    }
```

**PublisherClass.swift**

```
@Published var downloaded = false
//...
private init(){
}

func getFromAPI() async{
        let directory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let writeURL = directory.appendingPathComponent("data.json")

        guard let url = URL(string: apiURL) else {return}
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            try data.write(to: writeURL)
            self.downloaded = true
        } catch{
            print("error in PlaceDataService is \(error)")
        }
```

However, in the console, it will only print `received value false`. Even though that `downloaded` has become `true` and that data download has completed. There is just no new output.

I am pretty new to Combine pattern, so I am not exactly sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not keep a reference to the `AnyCancellable` returned by `sink`, so its lifetime ends when you return from `init`.

You get the first value, `false`, because that is the initial value of `downloaded`. However, by the time the download has finished and `downloaded` set to true, `init` has already returned, so the subscription has been cancelled.

You should keep a reference to the `AnyCancellable`:

```
let cancellable: AnyCancellable
private init(){
    print("Initiated")

    cancellable  = vm.$downloaded.sink(receiveCompletion: {
        print("received completion \($0)")
    }, receiveValue: {print("received value \($0)")})
```

Or use a set:

```
var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable>

...

vm.$downloaded.sink(receiveCompletion: {
        print("received completion \($0)")
    }, receiveValue: {print("received value \($0)")})
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Ahhh okay thank you very much! I always thought that was optional so that you could cancel the subscription. As a result, I didn't think it would affect how it works

Comment: What is the & symbol in Swift? I only know it from C as a pointer access... But I imagine it's not the same meaning here

Comment: @YanZhuang `&` can mean "turn this into a pointer", but in this case it is just how `inout` parameters are passed. The parameter of `store(in:)` is marked `inout`.